# How do I print the index of an array at i and i+1 index using java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, iterator, traversal

I'm a beginner and I'am trying to traverse a ListIterator and get the values at index i and i+1
for example:

```
// the value of the ListIterator is [1,2,3,4] 
and prints out:

0 1
1 2
2 3
```

The code keeps looping infinitely and I don't understand why.
here's my code

```
 ListIterator<String> iterSums = sums.listIterator();

     for(int i = 0; i <= sums.size() - 1; i++) {
             int prev = iterSums.previousIndex()+1;
             int next = iterSums.nextIndex()+1;
             iterSums.next();
             while(prev != sums.size()) {
                System.out.println(i+ " " + next);
     }
```

Comment: Could you specify what's **sumOfOnes** since iteration is based on it and I can't see it and it would help.

Comment: sorry! i edited it

Comment: In the while loop should use something like this.  `while (iterSums.hasNext ())`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
ListIterator iter = list.listIterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
   System.out.println(iter.nextIndex() + " " + iter.next());
}
```